# How does the damped Gauss-Newton-Method work?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I am not sure how I could apply a line search strategy to the Gauss-Newton-Method to solve nonlinear least square problems.

In a least square problem we have a function $f(t, x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ and a dataset

\begin{array}{|l|c|r|}
\hline
 & t & y\\
\hline
1 & t_1 & y_1\\
\hline
2 & t_2 & y_2\\
\hline
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
\hline
\end{array}

where $y$ is the observed output of $f$ for $t$.

For G-N to work, we need a start vector $x_0 = \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n\end{bmatrix}$

We define the residuum as:

$r = \begin{bmatrix}f(t_1, x) - y_1\\ f(t_2, x) - y_2\\ \vdots\end{bmatrix}$

Furthermore, we define Jacobi as

$J = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{df}{dx_1}(t_1, x) & \frac{df}{dx_2}(t_1, x) & \ldots\\
\frac{df}{dx_1}(t_2, x) & \frac{df}{dx_2}(t_2, x) & \ldots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\end{bmatrix}$

In each iteration of G-N, we can calculate the direction vector like this:

$J(x)^T \cdot J(x) \cdot d = J(x)^T\cdot r(x)$

For a line-search approach such as Wolfe-Powell, we need:

$\varphi(\alpha) = f(x + \alpha d)$ and $\varphi'(\alpha) = \nabla f(x + \alpha d)^T\cdot d$

In G-N, $\nabla f(x)$ is defined as $J(x)^T\cdot r(x)$. With this definition, we are able to use $\varphi'$ but I don't know how I can use $\varphi$? Which element $t$ of the dataset should I pass in?

I am looking forward to a explanation because pretty much all literature I found on that topic doesn't go into much detail on how this works.

In case I made mistakes in the definition of a least-squares problem, please help me out with that too.

Comment: The $t$ in the line search has nothing to do with the $t$ in the data set, better change the line search parameter to $\alpha,\tau$ or such.

Comment: I am sorry, that's a bit confusiong. You are right. But nevertheless - I don't know what kind of function I should use for $\varphi$

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow, $\varphi$ is the residual that you want to minimize, the square sum of the single residuals, restricted to the line through $x$ in direction $d$. The use of $f$ there is an error, it is a different function than the model class function that you initially use.

Comment: Okay, thank you. This makes sense..
But for whatever reason, WolfePowell gives me exceptionally small step sizes like $10^{-15}$

Comment: Any reasons why  Wolfe-Powell wouldn't work in this case? For example for $f(t, x_1, x_2) = x_1\cdot e^{x_2\cdot t}$

Comment: Small step sizes can happen if the iteration follows a narrow curved valley with a slight downward slope. Moving in a straight line will quickly leave the minimum curve, so "optimal" step sizes are small. You would need to allow a substantial overshoot to get reasonable step sizes. There are heuristics to control that, I do not have closer experiences with that. I think the "trust region" approach counts among them and is robust.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I don't know if this does help but does `f(t, x_1, x_2) = x_1 * exp(x_2 +  t)` have such a narrow valley? `1e-16` seems really extreme especially if a step size of `1` (in case I set it fixed to that value) solves the least-squares-problem after 10 iterations

Comment: That hints to an error or misunderstanding in the line-search implementation, as that step size is essentially zero. // Your model is redundant as $\exp(x_2)$ is just another factor. For the first version $x_1e^{x_2t}$ that should work.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more, what do you mean with `Your model is redundant`? Oh sure, the function should be `f(t, x_1, x_2) = x_1 * exp(x_2 * t)`

Comment: I saw this up to now as too trivial, but you are aware that the descent direction is the solution of $J^TJd=-J^TF$? If you do a line search in the wrong, opposite direction, then of course the best non-negative factor will be zero. // Also note that it is in general numerically better to compute $QR=J$ with a small QR decomposition and then solve $Rd=-Q^TF$.

Comment: Thank you! I think that solved part of my problem. WolfePowell now works at least for `f(t, x_1, x_2) = x_1 * exp(x_2 * t)` but not for my other test function: `g(t, x_1, x_2, x_3) = x_1 * exp( - (x_2^2 + x_3^2) * t) * ( sinh(x_3^2 * t) / (x_3^2) )` where it starts to put out correct step lengths (around 0.1 - 1) but suddenly drops to `10^{-12}` again and basically nothing changes (the value of `d` also drops to 0.001 in one direction at that time so I guess that's pretty to close to the minimum). If I use a constant step size like `0.125` the function converges again.

Comment: I might want to ask another question: I tried to solve the least-squares problem with a Quasi-Newton-Method such as BFGS. It worked fine again for the "easy" function but it returns wrong results for the second. Is this second function maybe just a brutal test function?

Comment: Your suspicions seem reasonable. As kind of debugging you could produce the graphs of $\phi$ over the interval $[0,2]$ to see if the line search does what you think it should do. // Yes, BFGS might be less stable globally. It only works like advertised if the iteration stays in a region where the Hessean that is approximated changes little to moderately.